# Split string at every nth linebreak using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm looking for a solution to split a string at every nth linebreak.
Lets say i have one string that has six lines

```
"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive\nSix\n"
```

So splitting at 3rd line break would give me something like

```
"One\nTwo\nThree\n" and "Four\nFive\nSix\n"
```

I've found solutions to do it at nth character, but i can't be definite of at what character length the nth break would occur. 
I hope my question is clear.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to split, try to match at least 3 lines.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Not quite sure how to do that, i've found patterns that match multiple lines, having trouble finding patterns that match every n number of lines.

Comment: @HaiderAli In this case, How do you want your output to be when your input is `One\n\n\n\n\nTwo\n\nThree\n\nFour\n\nFive\n\n\n\nSix\n`?

Comment: @Gurman That will not occur, the string is programatically prepared from an array. I'd rather split a string rather paginate an array ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), it's easier to use the [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method:

```
"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive\nSix\n".match(/(?=[\s\S])(?:.*\n?){1,3}/g);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LnQNXM/1)

pattern details:

```
(?=[\s\S]) # ensure there's at least one character (avoid a last empty match)

(?:.*\n?)  # a line (note that the newline is optional to allow the last line)

{1,3} # greedy quantifier between 1 and 3
      # (useful if the number of lines isn't a multiple of 3)
```

---

Other way with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive\nSix\n".split(/^/m).reduce((a, c, i) => {
    i%3  ?  a[a.length - 1] += c  :  a.push(c);
    return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight-forward:

```
(?:.+\n?){3}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ewdcrP/2).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
(?:  # open non-capturing group
.+   # the whole line
\n?  # a newline character, eventually but greedy
){3} # repeat the group three times
```